# Can we get Billling data per month for each GKE cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have exported the Billing data into Bigquery but I am only able to get the billing information for the overall GKE cluster per project on monthly basis.
I need to get the per month billing data for each GKE Cluster in a project.
Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, You can find in this doc https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign labels to you GKE clusters:

> A cluster label is a key-value pair that helps you organize your
> Google Cloud clusters. You can attach a label to each resource, then
> filter the resources based on their labels. Information about labels
> is forwarded to the billing system, so you can break down your billed
> charges by label.

see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-managing-labels).

And then with new billing rows you can group by label value, see [examples](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/bq-examples#group_by_label_value_for_a_specific_key)

```
SELECT
  labels.value as environment,
  SUM(cost) as cost
FROM `project.dataset.gcp_billing_export_v1_XXXXXX_XXXXXX_XXXXXX`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(labels) as labels
  ON labels.key = "environment"
GROUP BY environment;
```